# Ungeziefer and its meanings and connotations

Tags: meaning, connotation

Reading *Kluge's Etymological Dictionary* (published 1881, translated into English 1891) the word *Ungeziefer* has this description:

> **Ungeziefer**, noun, 'vermin', from the equivalent late Middle High German *ungezibere*, *unziver*, noun; properly 'unclean beast not suited for sacrifice'. It is based, in fact, on Old High German *zëbar*, 'beast of
>   offering', which is connected with the equivalent Anglo-Saxon *tîfer*. The
>   terms borrowed in Romance, Old French *toivre*, 'cattle', Portugese *zebro*, 'ox,
>   cow', prove that *zëbar* was applied to large animals, and that the
>   word was widely used in Old Teutonic.

[image]

How transparent was the religious connotation of this in the beginning of the 20th century? How transparent is it today amongst Germans?

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Geziefer) and [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geziefer) also lists the word *Geziefer* with about same meaning as the negated word: "*lästige, unerwünschte, schädliche kleine Tiere, vor allem Insekten"*. This word however, I didn't find in Kluge's dictionary.

I'm interested in the religious connotation because, Franz Kafka, a jew, has the protagonist in the novella *The Metamorphosis*, transformed into a "ungeheuren *Ungeziefer*". Could this, mostly understood as a beetle or a vermin, also be understood as ritually unclean (although I think *unrein* is the word used in the Torah)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nowadays there is zero religious connotation with that word, simple as that. It's clearly understood as vermin, no more and no less.

In the Third Reich, calling Jews "Ungeziefer" was part of the dehumanizing propaganda war against them. Theoretically, that could make for a strenuous religious association, but even then, the intention was clearly to portrait them as vermin.

Comment: Von Rechten heute noch gebräuchlich: Linke als Zecken zu verunglimpfen. Von Linken im Gegenzug für Investmentfonds: Heuschrecken. Den Zusammenhang "Ungeziefer - Luzifer" habe ich aber auch bis jetzt nicht wahrgenommen.

Comment: @userunknown: Could you write in English for those of us not speaking German?

Comment: @citizen: I'm sorry, but I have to answer `no`. Of course I could look up Zecken, verunglimpfen, Gegenzug, Heuschrecken. `Ungeziefer` and `Luzifer` have to stay in German, but I'm surely not able to find the right expression to translate "Rechte" and "Linke", as the terms are used in Germany, to British or American English. I guess similar terms are used very differently there.

Comment: Let me try: Right wingers call left wingers "ticks" and left wingers call international investors "locusts".